# upload_mimes filter has no effect

Tags: uploads

I wanted to add support for .wif files (text/plain) to my site (WP3.3.1). So I added the below function to my theme's `functions.php`. My theme is a child theme of [Suffusion](http://aquoid.com/news/themes/suffusion/).

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');

function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes=array() ) {
  $existing_mimes['wif'] = 'text/plain';
  return $existing_mimes;
}
```

It had no effect and .wif files continued to generate the security message when I tried to upload them.

So I looked at the source code for `get_allowed_mime_types()`. The only entry for 'text/plain' is this `'txt|asc|c|cc|h' => 'text/plain'`.  Just for fun I edited it to say this: `'txt|asc|c|cc|h|wif' => 'text/plain'`. That edit allowed .wif files to be uploaded.

But since editing core WP files is a bad idea, I tried another solution.  On the assumption that perhaps values in the $mimes array had to be unique, I tried changing the key that points to 'text/plain' with this function:

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');

function custom_upload_mimes($mimes=array()){
    $k='wif';
    $v='text/plain';
    if($ek=array_search($v,$mimes)){
        unset($mimes[$ek]);
        $ek.='|'.$k;
        $mimes[$ek]=$v;
    }
    return $mimes;
}
```

This, however, also does not allow .wif file upload.

So I think that either the `upload_mimes` filter is not being applied for some reason. Or, my filter is being overwritten by another.  I've tried both my functions with high (1) and low (PHP_MAX_INT) priority.  It has no effect. I also checked for .htaccess directives and their weren't any. Any ideas?

ETA
It turns out that some combination of plugins that includes BackUpWordPress causes filters attached to 'upload_mimes' to not run. I have not determined why this is and the people oat BackUpWordPress tell me that their plugin does not touch that filter.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the filter. Deregister the old key, to avoid conflicts. Then simply add your new one.

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'wpse44777_upload_mimes' );
function wpse44777_upload_mimes( $mime_types )
{
    // First we unregister the old key
    unset( $mime_types['txt|asc|c|cc|h'] );

    // Then we add a new one
    ! isset( $mime_types['txt|asc|c|cc|h|wif'] ) AND $mime_types['txt|asc|c|cc|h|wif'] = 'text/plain';

    return $mime_types;
}
```

Comment: Other than specifying the array index rather than searching for it, how is this different from my 2nd attempt (`if($ek=array_search($v,$mimes)){`...)? I unset the existing array member and then I add my own and return the array.  And yet it only works if I turn off BackUpWordPress.

Comment: @dnagirl Have overseen your `unset()`. In this case, it's simple: Blame the plugin. And yes, yours isn't really different. Just a little less readable and slower :) Please add your solution (if you found out why BackUpWordPress was causing this issue) and maybe report that to the author.

Comment: unfortunately, I haven't discovered why the plugin was causing the problem. Their codebase does not even touch the `upload_mimes()` filter. But if I deactivate it, all is good. BTW, the reason I used the loop was in case WP ever changed their key for 'text/plain'.

Comment: Just want to add to make sure you know the mime type of the file you're trying to upload by checking it on your file system (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227182/how-can-i-find-out-a-files-mime-typecontent-type). Also if you're using a multisite to make sure you go to Network Admin Area > Settings > Upload Settings in your WordPress multi-site network panel and use the setting called “Upload File Types” where you can add more file extensions which should be allowed on all blogs/sites on the multi-site network.

Comment: @kaiser - Why do the mime types need to be `unset`? It isn't also clear how the other approaches impact speed in comparison to you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'theme_restrict_mime_types' );
function theme_restrict_mime_types( $mime_types )
{
    $mime_types = array(
        'wif' => 'text/plain',
        'doc|docx' => 'application/msword',
        'jpg|jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
        'png' => 'image/png'
    );
    return $mime_types;
}
```

In this example I list all types that I allow (with WIF included). So you would need to add whats missing for your liking.

This works on my WP 3.3.1 install.

Comment: It turns out that my filter is not the problem. The issue is a conflict with a backup plugin. When the plugin is off, my filter works fine.  Thanks though.

Comment: this will kill all allowed mime types currently set by WP.  Probably not a good idea.

Comment: Maybe use `$mime_types .= array(`, so it appends them to the default ones.

Comment: @CiprianPopescu `$mime_types += ...`

Comment: @kaiser `+=` is for Javascript, `.=` is for PHP.

Comment: @CiprianPopescu lol. You're right. `.=` is to combine strings. Or better: To append one string to another. Shouldn't work on arrays. But to combine two arrays, you can simply use `+` (if I'm now not on the wrong language (ruby?) again) :)

Comment: Correct, didn't think about combining arrays. I'll stop here, as I'm going offtopic ;)

Comment: I know this is old but something that's important to check I think is the mime type of tile on your system before writing the callback. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227182/how-can-i-find-out-a-files-mime-typecontent-type

Answer (score 0):

This post is quite old, but I don't think that's the correct mime type any longer for WIF files.

```
function t4a_add_custom_upload_mimes( $allowed_mimes ) {
    $allowed_mimes['wif'] = 'application/watcherinfo+xml';
    return $allowed_mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 't4a_add_custom_upload_mimes' );
```

I will add that this is working locally for me, but *not* on my live sites so there's some other server conflict that I'm not aware of yet.

Comment: the `.wif` files in the original question are text/plain files. They are used in weaving software.

Comment: I knew they were weaving files as I was trying to help someone get uploads allowed on their site... but didn't know they were text. https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/watcherinfo+xml suggests the type should be `application/watcherinfo+xml` but as I've noted this isn't enough to get them uploading again on live sites.